# Windows WSL with Ubuntu LAMP - PHP not executing

Tags: php, apache, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was about to test if Windows 10 Pro with WSL running Ubuntu LAMP stack is already a good options for web development.

I tested 2 guides:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/setup-a-php-development-environment-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-9193ff28ae83/

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/using-wsl-and-mobaxterm-to-create-a-linux-dev-environment-on-windows

First I tested with Nginx and PHP7.2 but I had the issue that PHP was not executed but displayed. Then I gave Apache2 a try with PHP7.0 and I have the same issue.

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.0:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php7.0:
Module php7.0 already enabled

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```

There was never a PHP5 installed and there is nothing in apache about PHP5.

/etc/apache2/mods-available contains

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  867 Sep  2 15:31 php7.0.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  102 Sep  2 15:31 php7.0.load
```

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled contains the symlinks

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Oct 22 12:03 php7.0.conf -> ../mods-available/php7.0.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Oct 22 12:03 php7.0.load -> ../mods-available/php7.0.load
```

php7.0.load contains

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so
```

The module exists at this location.

Apache error.log looks also ok

```
[Tue Oct 22 14:06:32.548315 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1779:tid 140213335231424] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Oct 22 14:06:34.732188 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24776] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 22 14:06:34.732298 2019] [core:notice] [pid 24776] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

vHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    ServerName www.test.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev/test

    <Directory /var/www/dev/test/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_www.test.me.log
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/dev is a symlink to the mounted windows user dev folder

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19 Oct 22 11:30 dev -> /c/Users/name/dev/
```

Since Apache and Nginx have have the same issue it might be about the path to or the user/permissions but I couldn't find anything so far.

Would be nice if someone has an idea whats wrong.

Comment: I have completely the same issue. Tried different php versions, FPM and so on. Nothing helped

Comment: I have the same issue. There appears to be no httpd.conf file to check whether the PHP module is loading.

Comment: PHP 8 has been out for some time; did you try installing it?

Comment: Could you please share your Apache configuration where it says AddHandler for PHP?